# Entity framework how to map this relationship?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have

```
User:
 -ID
 -Name

Badge
 -ID
 -Name (E.G "User has made 100 posts", the same relationship as Stackoverflow)
```

So I've realised I need a third table, (as badges are defined in the DB aswell so I've created:

```
UserBadge
 -ID
 -User
 -Badge
```

So now in my User class I have

```
List<UserBadge> Badges;
```

Problem is, I'm going

```
Users.Find(1).Badges.Where(x => x.User == user && x.Badge = badgeIWant)
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

(Or something similar) Because... EF doesn't have the intelligence (I'm guessing) to automatically know that "Badges" should only include the ones where the User matches.

How should I do this? Was thinking I could have a custom getter for Badges, that has that LINQ conditional in it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is EF 4.3 code first:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Badge> Badges { get; set; }
    }

    public class Badge
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context()
            : base("Votes")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Badge> Badge { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Context context = new Context();
            User user = context.Users.Include("Badges").Where(u => u.ID == 1).SingleOrDefault();
            if(user != null)
            {
                //write your code.
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested it and this should work. This would typically be a many to many relationship because User can have many badges and 1 badge can belong to many users. If you run this code, you will find EF creates `BadgeUsers` table with BadgeID and UserID as foreign keys. From there on you can query and EF knows which badges you talking about.

Comment: Thank you for your reply its fantastic, sorry but why is the collection of users in Badge called Badges? Should it be called Users?

Comment: @William: Yeah, sorry :). It should be called Users. I just did copy paste from User model and forgot to change Badges. By the way, if you tick it as answer the general practice is to also vote up for that answer (The little top arrow above 0) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the badges of the user then just use `users.Find(1).Badges`. EF will automatically filter the badges related to the user.